# webservice (checkVatService) powershell

Tags: xml, web-services, powershell, wsdl

i want to use this webservice:

http://ec.europa.eu/taxation_customs/vies/services/checkVatService
Method: POST
Content-Type application/xml

this is my request:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:urn="urn:ec.europa.eu:taxud:vies:services:checkVat:types">
<soapenv:Header/>
<soapenv:Body>
    <urn:checkVat>
        <urn:countryCode>ES</urn:countryCode>
        <urn:vatNumber>A28017895</urn:vatNumber>
    </urn:checkVat>
</soapenv:Body>
```

The wsdl is here: http://ec.europa.eu/taxation_customs/vies/checkVatService.wsdl

How can i send the xml request with powershell and get the response there?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to use [`Invoke-Webrequest`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/powershell/reference/5.1/microsoft.powershell.utility/Invoke-WebRequest) to handle that.  Just set the `-Method` switch to POST and provide your xml as the body

Comment: when i try this i get this error:

Invoke-WebRequest: The response content cannot be parsed because the Internet Explorer engine is not available, or Internet Explorer's first-launch configuration is not complete. Specify the UseBasicParsing parameter and try again.

Comment: According to [This Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38005341/the-response-content-cannot-be-parsed-because-the-internet-explorer-engine-is-no) using the `-UseBasicParsing` switch as the error states should fix this problem.  it also seems that opening IE and completing the initial setup should work as well.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the [`New-WebServiceProxy`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/new-webserviceproxy?view=powershell-5.1) which is a more elegant solution in my opinion. You don't need to construct the `envelope` yourselve.

```
Function Get-ViesVatNumber {
[CmdletBinding()]
    param (
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true,
                   Position=0)]
        $CountryCode,

        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true,
                   Position=1)]
        $VatNumber
    )

    $Vies = New-WebServiceProxy -Uri "http://ec.europa.eu/taxation_customs/vies/checkVatService.wsdl" -Class "checkVat"

    $Valid = $false
    $Name = ""
    $Address = ""

    $DateChecked = $Vies.checkVat([ref]$CountryCode, [ref]$VatNumber, [ref]$Valid, [ref]$Name, [ref]$Address)

    $Properties = @{
        'CountryCode'   = $CountryCode
        'VatNumber'     = $VatNumber
        'Valid'         = $Valid
        'Name'          = $Name
        'Address'       = $Address
        'DateChecked'   = $DateChecked
    }

    $Company = New-Object -TypeName PSCustomObject -Property $Properties

    Write-Output $Company
}
```

Example with a valid VAT

```
Get-ViesVatNumber -CountryCode "BE" -VatNumber "0420429375"

DateChecked : 02/08/2018 00:00:00
Name        : Comm.VA ALPRO
VatNumber   : 0420429375
Address     : VLAMINGSTRAAT 28
              8560 WEVELGEM
Valid       : True
CountryCode : BE
```

Example with an invalid VAT

```
Get-ViesVatNumber -CountryCode "BE" -VatNumber "0420429335"

DateChecked : 02/08/2018 00:00:00
Name        : ---
VatNumber   : 0420429335
Address     : ---
Valid       : False
CountryCode : BE
```

Answer (score 0):

To make it even better: when entering your own VAT number on the VIES check website, you will receive a consultation number (for administration purposes a proof that the number was valid when you checked it).

You can also request this consultation number by calling the "checkVatApprox" webservice instead of the "checkVat". By doing this you need the following amendments (a LOT parameters):

```
        $Valid = $false
        $Name = ""
        $Address = ""
        $Identifier = ""
        $TraderCompanyType = ""
        $TraderStreet = ""
        $TraderPostcode = "" 
        $TraderCity = ""
        $TraderNameMatch = 1
        $TraderNameMatchSpecified = $false
        $TraderCompanyTypeMatch = 1
        $TraderCompanyTypeMatchSpecified = $false
        $TraderStreetMatch =1
        $TraderStreetMatchSpecified = $false
        $TraderPostcodeMatch = 1
        $TraderPostcodeMatchSpecified = $false
        $TraderCityMatch = 1
        $TraderCityMatchSpecified = $false
        $RequesterCountryCode = "YourCountryCode"
        $RequesterVatNumber = "YourVATNumber"

        $DateChecked = $Vies.checkVatApprox([ref]$CountryCode, [ref]$VatNumber, [ref]$Name, [ref]$TraderCompanyType, [ref]$TraderStreet, [ref]$TraderPostcode, [ref]$TraderCity, $RequesterCountryCode, $RequesterVatNumber, [ref]$Valid, [ref]$Address, [ref]$TraderNameMatch, [ref]$TraderNameMatchSpecified, [ref]$TraderCompanyTypeMatch, [ref]$TraderCompanyTypeMatchSpecified, [ref]$TraderStreetMatch, [ref]$TraderStreetMatchSpecified, [ref]$TraderPostcodeMatch, [ref]$TraderPostcodeMatchSpecified, [ref]$TraderCityMatch, [ref]$TraderCityMatchSpecified, [ref]$Identifier)
```

Please note that the $RequesterCountryCode and $RequesterVatNumber don't require [ref]'s. This made me look for ages to this request before noticing.

Now all works fine and if you add this:

```
     $Properties = @{
    'CountryCode'   = $CountryCode
    'VatNumber'     = $VatNumber
    'Valid'         = $Valid
    'Name'          = $Name
    'Address'       = $Address
    'DateChecked'   = $DateChecked
    'Consultation'  = $Identifier
     }
```

you will get the following response:

```
Get-ViesVatNumber -CountryCode "BE" -VatNumber "0420429375"

DateChecked : 8/13/2019 10:00:00 PM
Name        : Comm.VA ALPRO
VatNumber   : 0420429375
Address     : VLAMINGSTRAAT 28
              8560 WEVELGEM
Valid       : True
CountryCode : BE
Consultation: WAPIAAAAWyQb9ELI
```

The other fields like TraderNameMatch, you can use them as a response as well, but as far as i know, only Spain supports entering an address for validation purposes. The other countries don't.