# Powershell invoke-webrequest not working

Tags: windows, powershell, server, prtg

I have a Powershell script that is supposed to run an `Invoke-WebRequest` against a site. I want to use this script with PRTG Network Monitor to ensure that a web server is up and running properly.

Currently, the script works running from my local machine as well as running with my domain credentials on the probe server. However, it doesn't run when logged in with the local admin credentials which is what PRTG uses.

I've narrowed it down to a single line,

```html
Invoke-WebRequest $uri -Method POST -Body $body -TimeoutSec 10
```

It appears that for whatever reason, when using this account, `Invoke-WebRequest` will not work. When running that line, it doesn't produce anything, no error, warning, or output. Both `$uri` and `$body` variables are already defined as well.

Even if I'm logged into the probe server with the local admin PRTG account and run Powershell as another user (using my own credentials) it still fails to produce anything.

Why would a local admin account not be able to run `Invoke-WebRequest`? This is happening on a Windows Server 2012R2 with PSVersion 4.0.

Comment: YES!!! That worked. Thank you so much. This has been killing me for the past couple days.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

[Turning my comment into an answer]

In Windows PowerShell, `Invoke-WebRequest` uses the Internet Explorer engine for parsing websites, unless you tell it not to. IE has a lot of restrictions - coming from its security model of Trusted Sites/security zones, IE Enhanced Security, overrides by Group Policy, maybe more, and it looks like you'd tried everything else sensible, and it was worth trying to test that directly.

This switch:

```
Invoke-WebRequest -UseBasicParsing ....
```

avoids the IE engine and makes a HTTP request and processes the response all within C#/.Net.

The trade-off is that you get plain text results to work with and can't access the page through the HTML DOM, no `getElementByTagName()` or anything that needs a live browser engine to work.

Comment: Thanks for this. Finally figured out why some background job did not work while a client running the same script did work. Saved my weekend (y)

Comment: still fails, I get `Invoke-WebRequest : Die Verbindung mit dem Remoteserver kann nicht hergestellt werden`

Comment: I run a webserver on port 3000 and put: `Invoke-WebRequest -Uri http://localhost:3000 -UseBasicParsing`. I got the error from above. Howerver, `Invoke-WebRequest -Uri http://test.de` works.

Comment: @Timo you're doing a different thing, and getting a different error, and this question was 2 years ago. Probably not the right place to troubleshoot it. I can run `NetCat` from the nmap project in one window using `ncat -l -p 3000` to listen on port 3000 like a webserver, and `invoke-webrequest -uri http://localhost:3000 -UseBasicParsing` in another window to connect, and the connection works, and the netcat window gets the HTTP request headers. I'm guessing you have a local firewall, or the webserver isn't configured to allow the connection.

Comment: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46367395/1705829) helped, maybe the `ie` was not introduced, seems a firewall issue. Btw do you have `ncat` for powershell? I cannot find it. Question is 3 years old, time flys

Comment: @Timo oh, good find!  I do not have an ncat specifically for PowerShell, it's just the standard Windows downlad of nmap. You can open a socket and listen in PowerShell/.Net [but it's not trivial to type at a command line](https://riptutorial.com/powershell/example/18117/tcp-listener)

Comment: `-UseBasicParsing` solves an alarming number of problems with Invoke-WebRequest. Poor design IMO?

Comment: @JeremyMorren the PowerShell team made the cmdlet more useful and convenient by leaning on Windows' built-in browser engine. Then Microsoft abandoned IE and left it to rot for years while the web moved on. I like the "batteries included" approach more than the "install a module from the gallery for everything" approach. Having to find, install, learn and use Selenium just so you can `.Document.Links` is a real shame when Windows has IE, Edge/Edgium, often Outlook and more HTML parsers inside it somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

In our case, it turned out there was a proxy setting in internet explorer (which Powershell uses by default), but we couldn't clear it because it was a company laptop and so we had to first `disable` the group policy and then clear it in Internet Explorer. Open gpedit.msc and then go here `Computer Configuration -> Administrative Template -> Windows Components -> Internet Explorer -> Prevent Changing proxy settings` and then disable it.

[image]