# Download all pdfs on a webpage with PowerShell

Tags: powershell, pdf, download

I found online the following code to download all the pdfs on a webpage:

```
$psPage = Invoke-WebRequest "https://www.pi.infn.it/~rizzo/ingegneria/appunti_fisII_ing_mecc/
"
$urls = $psPage.ParsedHtml.getElementsByTagName("A") | ? {$_.href -like "*.pdf"} | Select-Object -ExpandProperty href

$urls | ForEach-Object {Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $_ -OutFile ($_ | Split-Path -Leaf)}
```

but PS gave me the error:

```
Invoke-WebRequest : The response content cannot be parsed because the Internet Explorer engine is not
available, or Internet Explorer's first-launch configuration is not complete. Specify the UseBasicParsing
parameter and try again.
At C:\Users\Raffaele\Desktop\Nuova cartella\a.ps1:1 char:11
+ $psPage = Invoke-WebRequest "https://www.pi.infn.it/~rizzo/ingegneria ...
+           ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotImplemented: (:) [Invoke-WebRequest], NotSupportedException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : WebCmdletIEDomNotSupportedException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeWebReq
   uestCommand

You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
At C:\Users\Raffaele\Desktop\Nuova cartella\a.ps1:2 char:1
+ $urls = $psPage.ParsedHtml.getElementsByTagName("A") | ? {$_.href -li ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull

Split-Path : Cannot bind argument to parameter 'Path' because it is null.
At C:\Users\Raffaele\Desktop\Nuova cartella\a.ps1:4 char:66
+ ... h-Object {Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $_ -OutFile ($_ | Split-Path -Leaf)}
+                                                        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Split-Path], ParameterBindingValidationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationErrorNullNotAllowed,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.S
   plitPathCommand

Invoke-WebRequest : Cannot validate argument on parameter 'Uri'. The argument is null or empty. Provide an
argument that is not null or empty, and then try the command again.
At C:\Users\Raffaele\Desktop\Nuova cartella\a.ps1:4 char:48
+ $urls | ForEach-Object {Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $_ -OutFile ($_ | Spli ...
+                                                ~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Invoke-WebRequest], ParameterBindingValidationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationError,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeWebReques
   tCommand
```

How can I overcome this problem? Why it requires internet explorer engine?

---

EDIT: I tried to modify the code in this way:

```
$site = "https://www.pi.infn.it/~rizzo/ingegneria/appunti_fisII_ing_mecc/"
$psPage = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $site -UseBasicParsing
$urls = $psPage.ParsedHtml.getElementsByTagName("A")
$urls |  where {$_.pathname -like "*pdf"} | % {Invoke-WebRequest -Uri "$site$($_.pathname)" -OutFile $_.pathname }
```

and the error is:

```
You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
At C:\Users\Raffaele\Desktop\Nuova cartella\a.ps1:3 char:1
+ $urls = $psPage.ParsedHtml.getElementsByTagName("A")
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull
```

---

EDIT 2 I tried to modify the code in this way. New code:

```
$psPage = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri -UseBasicParsing "https://www.pi.infn.it/~rizzo/ingegneria/appunti_fisII_ing_mecc/"
$urls = $psPage.ParsedHtml.getElementsByTagName("A") | ? {$_.href -like "*.pdf"} | Select-Object -ExpandProperty href
$urls | ForEach-Object {Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $_ -OutFile ($_ | Split-Path -Leaf)}
```

The Windows PowerShell gave me a new error:

```
Invoke-WebRequest : Missing an argument for parameter 'Uri'. Specify a parameter of type 'System.Uri' and
try again.
At C:\Users\Raffaele\Desktop\Nuova cartella\b.ps1:1 char:29
+ $psPage = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri -UseBasicParsing "https://www.pi.inf ...
+                             ~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Invoke-WebRequest], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MissingArgument,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeWebRequestCommand

You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
At C:\Users\Raffaele\Desktop\Nuova cartella\b.ps1:2 char:1
+ $urls = $psPage.ParsedHtml.getElementsByTagName("A") | ? {$_.href -li ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull

Split-Path : Cannot bind argument to parameter 'Path' because it is null.
At C:\Users\Raffaele\Desktop\Nuova cartella\b.ps1:3 char:66
+ ... h-Object {Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $_ -OutFile ($_ | Split-Path -Leaf)}
+                                                        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Split-Path], ParameterBindingValidationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationErrorNullNotAllowed,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.S
   plitPathCommand

Invoke-WebRequest : Cannot validate argument on parameter 'Uri'. The argument is null or empty. Provide an
argument that is not null or empty, and then try the command again.
At C:\Users\Raffaele\Desktop\Nuova cartella\b.ps1:3 char:48
+ $urls | ForEach-Object {Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $_ -OutFile ($_ | Spli ...
+                                                ~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Invoke-WebRequest], ParameterBindingValidationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationError,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeWebReques
   tCommand
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [The response content cannot be parsed because the Internet Explorer engine is not available, or](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38005341/the-response-content-cannot-be-parsed-because-the-internet-explorer-engine-is-no)

Comment: The answer is in the error message: either complete the first launch of IE OR use the -UseBasicParsing parameter.

Comment: Hi @DougMaurer I added -UseBasicParsing, but I still have error (fortunately another kind of error)

Comment: I suggest you read the error messages, the new error message you recieve is clear (hint: you did -usebasicparsing but after that you forgot the space between that and the url)

Comment: @bluuf thank you for the suggestion. I edited the code and wrote the "new" error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**In your way** : First you have to remove "about:" in your URL or replace it by nothing :

```
$site = "https://www.pi.infn.it/~rizzo/ingegneria/appunti_fisII_ing_mecc/"
$psPage = Invoke-WebRequest $site
$urls = $psPage.ParsedHtml.getElementsByTagName("A") | ? {$_.href -like "*.pdf"} | Select-Object -ExpandProperty href | ForEach-Object {$_.replace("about:", "")}
```

Second you have to recreate full URL  :

```
$urls | ForEach-Object {Invoke-WebRequest -Uri "$site$_" -OutFile $_ }
```

**But you can simplify** using `"textcontent"` or `"pathname"` :

```
$site = "https://www.pi.infn.it/~rizzo/ingegneria/appunti_fisII_ing_mecc/"
$psPage = Invoke-WebRequest $site
$urls = $psPage.ParsedHtml.getElementsByTagName("A")
$urls |  where {$_.pathname -like "*pdf"} | % {Invoke-WebRequest -Uri "$site$($_.pathname)" -OutFile $_.pathname }
```

Comment: Have you try mine ? Your URI is not complet.

Comment: Hi @JPBlanc, in the first edit I reported your code and the corresponding error.

Comment: Strange it works for me. Try it again with URL hardcoded ?the last one works definitly in a brand new shell. Perhaps a trouble with an hidden character ?

Comment: @GennaroArguzzi, just copy pas the last 4 lines.

Comment: I did it, but PS gave me the error about internet explorer. If possible, upload a short video (to record with Windows press windows key+G).

Comment: @GennaroArguzzi I upload the video [here](https://1drv.ms/v/s!As-2VC0zf0EcgaM-F29gNTKCEAtHww?e=dkxceP)

Comment: Hello @JPBlanc thank you very much for the video. Maybe in your case it works because you have internet explorer. The  $PSVersionTable command gave me the same table shown in your video.

Comment: @GennaroArguzzi : I reproduce your trouble just remove `-UseBasicParsing`

Comment: thank you very much for your precoius help. The problem was my virtual machine; on the physical machine, your code works