# PowerShell, force Internet Explorer to perform its first-launch configuration?

Tags: powershell, internet-explorer, invoke-webrequest

I often hit the dreaded `Internet Explorer's first-launch configuration is not complete. Specify the UseBasicParsing parameter and try again` error when using Invoke-WebRequest.

Various [pages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38005341/the-response-content-cannot-be-parsed-because-the-internet-explorer-engine-is-no) point out this issue and the use of the `UseBasicParsing` switch, but it is an annoyance to have to put that into every command.

Is there a way that I can declare, at the start of a script, some commands to force Internet Explorer to silently perform its first-launch configuration and accept all defaults so that the `UseBasicParsing` switch is no longer required?

Comment: Try this at start of the script: `$PSDefaultParameterValues=@{"Invoke-WebRequest:UseBasicParsing"=$true}`. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_parameters_default_values?view=powershell-7.2

Comment: That's really fascinating, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58465946/3949759) on the page you provided actually suggests setting the registry value with PowerShell that will disable the first run wizard for Internet Explorer and allow you to use Invoke-WebRequest without `-UseBasicParsing` parameter.

```
Set-ItemProperty -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main" -Name "DisableFirstRunCustomize" -Value 2
```

Comment: Ah, I did not notice that one, thanks, I will make use of this.